# CODIGO HTTP 304 AL CONSUMIR UN SERVICIO CON FETCH

Tags: javascript, nodejs, fetch

Tengo una api rest que funciona a la perfeccion con postman, pero al momento de consumirla en el cliente con fetch me devuelve un codigo 304

NOTA: Esto me pasa cuando envio el token en las cabeceras, si no envio el token todo funciona normal

Comment: Muy buenas JhonF, podrias añadir el código para que se mas facil para la comunidad echarte una mano?. Por otra parte, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera **medalla**, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Aclara algo más, tal como: ¿Se trata de un get o un post? ¿La misma petición funciona sin token? Pon el código que puedas, tanto del frontend como del backend

Comment: Entiendo que postman envía explícitamente el header `no-cache`. Si no pones ese header en tu fetch entonces el API te responde un header que singnifica que el contenido no se ha modificado, y eso es porque además el browser, con buenas intenciones, almacena el resultado de la petición por defecto. Si el API lo soporta, prueba enviar el token en el query string.

Comment: Gracias a todo, ya lo pude resolver aunque no se porque razon pasa eso, lo que hize fue utilizar axios y ya, vuelvo y digo no se porque con fetch no me llegaba la data